# How find into Koa context the WebSocket and Request connected to a connection?

Tags: node.js, websocket, koa, ws

I'd like connect the Koa application used mainly for easy handling of the middlewares, the { createServer } from http for handling the http server events, and the { WebSocketServer } from ws to handling the WebSocket connection and WebSocketServer events ... all connected as:

```
const app = new Koa()
const server = createServer(app.callback())
const wss = new WebSocketServer({server})
```

I'm using the Router middleware too for serve the different path and methods. But my question is how i can get the Koa context for a WebSocket connection (ws, req):

```
 wss.on('connection', async (ws, req) => { // Koa ctx ?? })
```

Or how can i get the WebSocket object into a Koa middleware (eg. a route):

```
router.get('/get', async (ctx, next) => { // WebSocket ?? })
```

Or inside a general Koa middleware:

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => { // WebSocket ??})
```

I'd like to understand how the wss (WebSocketServer) is connected with app (Koa Application) through the http server!